# Error The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack-dev-server

after going through all the threads available, I'm still not able to resolve the problem. I cloned the angular2 quickstart project.
All module versions are up to date
the repo link is : [github.com/ashishsurana/portfolio](https://github.com/ashishsurana/portfolio)

Comment: What version of node and npm are you running?

Comment: Try upgrading 'typescript' to latest

Comment: @ConradLotz npm version is - 4.1.2 and node version is v7.6.0

and @daan.desmedt I installed the lates version by ```npm install -g typescript```  and version is 2.3.4

Comment: hover over the dependency for compiler-cli and check its latest version. Ensure that your package json also has the same version mentioned for installation.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to clone the angular seed project.

Just install the Angular CLI globally in your system using:

`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

then you can use it to create a new project

`ng new my-project`

and run it:

`cd my-project
ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing existing dependencies and run `npm install` again. Make sure that you have the latest typescript(at least version 2.2). This worked for me!.